# get the folder of the symfony installation, not from the app direction

Tags: symfony

i am using:

```
$script = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir();
```

but with this i got the following result:

```
/var/www/symfony/app
```

Is there a way that i can get the following result?

```
/var/www/symfony
```

This doesn't works:

```
$script = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . "../exportscript/export.php";
```

I have now fixed this problem with:

```
$script = str_replace("/app", "", $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . "/exportscript/export.php");
```

but i dont think that this is the correct way for symfony.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bubble up of one directory with:

```
dirname($this->get('kernel')->getRootDir());
```

This should give you

```
/var/www/symfony //without trailing slash
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

`$script = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . "/../exportscript/export.php";`

With a slash directly after `$this->get('kernel')->getRootDir()` since it gives you the output `/var/www/symfony/app`